# Good resources on Aalen additive models (survival)

Tags: survival, references

I'm trying to do some modelling of time to event data and for various reasons, the Aalen additive model seems promising.

I'm using the `aareg` function in the `survival` package, but I'm struggling to find much literature (that isn't paywalled) to get more of a feel for the procedure.

Does anyone have any suggestions of some anything reasonably in depth, but accessible to someone without expert level knowledge of newer survival analysis techniques?

Answer (score 1):

[Klein, J. P. & Moeschberger, M. L. (2003). Survival Analysis: Techniques for
Censored and Truncated Data. New York: Springer, 2nd ed.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b97377)

Chapter 10 is about Additive Hazards Regression Models. 
Section 10.2 specifically deals with Aalen’s Nonparametric, Additive Hazard Model.

---

A couple of other references:

[Aalen, O. (1980). A model for nonparametric regression analysis of count-
ing processes. In Mathematical Statistics and Probability Theory, W. Klo-
necki, A. Kozek & J. Rosiński, eds., vol. 2 of Lecture Notes in Statistics.
New York: Springer, pp. 1–25.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-7397-5_1)

[Yin, G. & Cai, J. (2004). Additive hazards model with multivariate failure
time data. Biometrika 91, 801–818.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20441145)

[Martinussen, Torben, S. T. H. (2006). Dynamic Regression Models for
Survival Data. Springer.](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences,+medicine+&+health/book/978-0-387-20274-7)

Comment: All of these are behind some kind of pay wall. Can you provide alternative links or resources?

Comment: I can access them from work and can send them to you if you wish

Comment: Ocram, many thanks for your answers, and I might need to just expense one of the books you've listed. However, I'd advise against offering to breach copyright on a public forum, much as I appreciate the gesture.